# joomla ajax POST not posting

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, joomla

Running Joomla 3.5.1 and I want to have an ajax call to pull data from another server, this works in another environment without any problem but cannot get it to work in Joomla.  I found where I had to change $ to jQuery so the updates to the div work and the ajax url appears to work however there is no JSon data being sent for the post and therefore nothing sent back.

```
function GetProduct(ID) {
jQuery('#div_Options').text('');
var dataObj = "{\"PCID\": \"" + ID + "\"}";
try {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://server.com/ajax/productoptions.asmx/GetTest',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataObj,
        cache: false,
        success: function (outData) {
            $("#div_Options").text(outData.d);
        },
        error: function (outData, msg) {
            jQuery("#div_Options").text('Ajax Error - ' + msg.toString());
        }
    });
}
catch (err) {
    jQuery("#div_Options").text('Code Error');
}
```

}

Do I need to create a module or is there a simple fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

If Ajax is working in principle, then the problem most likely lies with your `data` field. Check if that field contains the right information as expected by the remote server. Also, what do you get when you do `alert(msg.toString());` in the `error` part?

Doing it in a module will not solve your problem - the code is already working. It's just that the `data` is field is most likely wrong.